# Problema ao usar a função getch() em C

Tags: c, c++

Estou escrevendo um jogo simples que se baseia na travessia de um número no primeiro elemento da matriz até o último elemento. Porém, estou querendo usar a função `getch()` para que o elemento se mova pela matriz imediatamente após alguma tecla ser digitada, mas o elemento só se move apos eu apertar o caractere "b".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>

void matriz(int v[][30], int i, int j, int bomb);

int main()
{
srand(time(NULL));
int maze[30][30], i, j, bomb = rand()%70;
puts("Ola, Benvindo ao Maze game.\nOs comandos sao simples\nW para cima\nA para a esquerda\nS para baixo\nD para direita\nVoce comeca na primeira posicao e devera chegar ate a ultima\nsem passar por cima de nenhum 1 ou 2 mas, voce EXPLODIR o 2 apertando 'b'\n(Sendo que vc so pode usar uma determinada qtd de bombas!)\nMAXIMIZE a tela, tecle enter e divirta-se");
getchar();
fflush(stdin);
system("cls");
for (i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 30; j++)
    {
        if (i == 29 && j == 29)
        {
            maze[i][j] = 0;
        } else if(i == 0 && j == 0)
        {
            maze[i][j] = 5;
        }else
        {
            maze[i][j] = rand()%3;
        }
        printf("%d ", maze[i][j]);
    }
    puts("");
}
printf("\nvoce tem %d bombas\n", bomb);
i = j = 0;
matriz(maze, i, j, bomb);
return 0;
}

void matriz(int v[][30], int i, int j, int bomb)
{
int a, b;
char direcao;
do
{
    direcao = getch(); //AQUI!
    switch(direcao)
    {
        case 'w':
            v[i][j] = 0;
            i--;
            break;
        case 'a':
            v[i][j] = 0;
            j--;
            break;
        case 's':
            v[i][j] = 0;
            i++;
            break;
        case 'd':
            v[i][j] = 0;
            j++;
            break;
        case 'b':
            if (bomb == 0)
            {
                direcao = 0;
            } else {
                printf("\7");
            bomb--;
            if (v[i + 1][j] == 2)
            {
                v[i + 1][j] = 0;
            }
            if (v[i - 1][j] == 2)
            {
                v[i - 1][j] = 0;
            }
            if (v[i][j + 1] == 2)
            {
                v[i][j + 1] = 0;
            }
            if (v[i][j - 1] == 2)
            {
                v[i][j - 1] = 0;
            }
            }
        default:
            direcao = 0;
    }
} while(direcao);
if (i < 0 || j < 0 || i > 29 || j > 29 || v[i][j] == 1 || v[i][j] == 2)
{
    puts("GAME OVER!!!");
    exit(1);
} else if (i == 29 && j == 29)
{
    system("cls");
    v[i][j] = 5;
    for (a = 0; a < 30; a++)
    {
        for (b = 0; b < 30; b++)
        {
            printf("%d ", v[a][b]);
        }
        puts("");
    }
    puts("Parabens Voce venceu!!!");
    exit(0);
} else
{
    v[i][j] = 5;
}
system("cls");
for (a = 0; a < 30; a++)
{
    for (b = 0; b < 30; b++)
    {
        printf("%d ", v[a][b]);
    }


    puts("");
}
printf("\nvoce tem %d bombas\n", bomb);
matriz(v, i, j, bomb);
}
```

Comment: Não parece haver problema com o getch() parece haver problema com a lógica dos outros case ou outra parte do código. Você já debugou para ver como ele está executando? De qualquer forma use outra função, não use nada que esteja no `conio.h`, prefira a `getchar()`, por exemplo. Veja como isto está "funcionando" (é, tem problemas), o problema deve estar na lógica, mas não sei bem o que você quer. http://ideone.com/uGBxNC

Comment: Realmente, o erro não estava no getch() mas sim no while. Quando eu fiz While( condicao == 0) e adicionei o break no final de case 'b', funcionou perfeito. obrigado

Comment: Vou colocar uma resposta para não ficar aberto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar evite usar o `getch()` ou qualquer coisa que esteja presente no `conio.h`. Use o `getchar()`que faz a mesma coisa de forma padrão e confiável.

O problema não é nesta função, ela está funcionando corretamente como pode ser [demonstrado no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/uGBxNC).

O problema está na lógica. O código não está executando o que você deseja e só *debugando* para entender o que está acontecendo passo-a-passo e ver onde a falha ocorre.

Pelo comentário parece que já achou onde estava a falha.