# problemas depois de compilar C++ com o compilador G++

Tags: c++, compiladores

estou com um problema aqui depois de compilar um programa em C++ utilizando o compilador g++, depois que compilo tudo, tento abrir o arquivo executável, então abre o meu cmd do windows(utilizo o windows 10), o problema e que quando o terminal começa a mostrar algo ele automáticamente fecha, como soluciono isso? já tentei usar a funções getch() e scanf() mas nada aconteceu

PROGRAMA

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){
    printf("Teste");
}
```

Comment: Pode colocar o programa ?

Comment: pronto, já coloquei o programa

Answer (score 1):

Sim, esse é o esperado mesmo, afinal não tem nenhum loop segurando ou "pause" para evitar, o programa roda o que tem que rodar e entrega o `main()` então o processo termina e a janela fecha, esse é o efeito exatamente esperado, não é nenhum problema com o compilador e sim com o seu entendimento.

Programa com interface grafica não fecham porque tem um "loop" interno (+ou- assim), que previne a finalização do processo enquanto houver a janela aberta.

Se quiser impedir que a janela feche basta usar `pause` (no windows creio eu)

```
#include <stdio.h>  /* printf */
#include <stdlib.h> /* system */

void main(){
    printf("Teste");
    system("pause");
}
```

Ou um exemplo que você pode fazer é arrastar o seu executável após compilado para dentro da janela do `cmd`, aperte o <kbd>Enter</kbd> na tela do `cmd` vai aparecer a resposta:

[image: teste]

---

### `getch`, `getche` e `getchar`

Aguarda digitar algo para finalizar:

```
#include <stdio.h> /* printf */
#include <conio.h> /* getch */

int main() {
    printf("teste");
    printf("\nPressione qualquer tecla para finalizar");
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Aguarda digitar algo e envia o que foi digitado para o output:

```
#include <stdio.h> /* printf */
#include <conio.h> /* getch e getche */

int main(){
    printf("teste");

    printf("\nDigite uma letra ou numero:\n");
    getche();

    printf("\nDigite qualquer coisa para finalizar");
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

No entanto conforme esta resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/75216/3635, o uso de qualquer coisa relacionada ao `conio.h` pode não ser confiável, então use `getchar`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    printf("Digite algo:");

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Se precisar pegar a saída:

```
#include <stdio.h> /* printf e getchar */

int main (){
    printf("Digite algo:");

    int test = getchar();
    putchar(test);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: obg, sou iniciante, mas valeu ai pela atençao

Comment: @LucasGabrielSanches se uma a resposta lhe resolveu o problema marque-a como correta por favor. Leia: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/3635